# Gradle and Eclipse project references

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I'm using Gradle with Eclipse and am trying to reference Project1 from Project2 (both under the same root directory), like so:

settings.gradle:

```
include ':Project1'
project(':Project1').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../Project1')
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':Project1')
 ...}
```

Project1 is also referenced through the build path. But eclipse/gradle does not recompile and instead uses include the old jar classes. I've also tried to set the plugin to `apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'`.

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?

Comment: I think you have to import both, Project1 and Project2 in your settings.gradle. If they both on the same have a look on http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html section "56.3.2.2. Flat layouts"

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity, do you have a block like this somewhere in your build.gradle

```
eclipse.project {
  referencedProjects 'Project1'
}
```

I ask because, if you don't tell Eclipse that this project references Project1, it won't be included in the build path.